# flag.StringVar with struct as destination

Tags: go

I'm attempting to capture flags and the parsed values into a struct.  What I have below works, but only on strings. When I encounter a boolean it fails so I'm trying to use an interface type without success.

```
type Commands struct {
    appDescription string
    flagsets map[string]Command
}

type Command struct {
    Flagset *flag.FlagSet
    parsed map[string]*string
}


command.parsed = make(map[string]string)

func main() {
   var command Command
   command.parsed = make(map[string]string)

   flagName := "appImportFlags"
   command.Flagset = flag.NewFlagSet(flagName, flag.ExitOnError)    


   command.Flagset.StringVar(command.parsed["test"], "arg", "", "description")
}
```

This works, but when I use a Boolean as in:\

```
   command.Flagset.Bool(command.parsed["test"], "arg", "", "description")
```

It fails because parsed is a string.  So I change it to an interface:

```
type Command struct {
        Flagset *flag.FlagSet
        parsed map[string]*interface{}
    }
```

Then it says I can't use a type *interface{} as a *string

Comment: it needs to be `parsed map[string]interface{}`, a `*interface{}` means you have something with the type `interface{}`, and then got a pointer to it (e.g. https://play.golang.org/p/-j3p8u7gf__z)

Comment: when I do that it says: cannot use command.parsed["test"] (type interface {}) as type *string in argument to command.Flagset.StringVar: need type assertion

Comment: right.  so do a type assertion: `command.parsed["test"].(*string)`

Comment: @dave, thank you dave, pointer (*) in the type assertion was what I was missing.  THANKS